# Не могу подклчить actionbarsherlock так как он конфликтует с appcompat-v7

Tags: android

Вобщем мне достался супер мега старый  дохлый проект на `ANT`  и `actionbarsherlock`(((( я хочу его перенести на `gradle`  но возникла проблема. конфликт `appcompat-v7` и `actionbarsherlock` так как они использую одни и теже ресурсы:

```
E:\gradle\DriverClient\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-wallet\7.8.0\res\values\wallet_colors.xml
    Error:(2) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined
    Error:(2) Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
    Error:(2) Attribute "divider" has already been defined
    Error:(2) Attribute "background" has already been defined
    Error:(2) Attribute "backgroundSplit" has already been defined
    Error:(2) Attribute "navigationMode" has already been defined
    Error:(2) Attribute "displayOptions" has already been defined
  .............................
```

я попытался удалить `appcompat-v7` но у меня не вышло. он удаляется только если так же убрать `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'`  а они мне нужны. как это исправить?

Comment: видимо рефакторить `ActionBarSherlock` на `SupportActionBar` аппкомпата

Comment: так и решил 10 минут назад. или пусть увольняют или я переделаю все нафиг

Comment: они не совместимы, ActionBarSherlock больше не поддерживается, его функционал полностью покрывает SupportActionBar

Comment: а вы не подключайте все компоненты `com.google.android.gms:play-services:` подключите только то что вам нужно `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:`

Comment: Мой Вам совет — сносите этот пережиток от греха подальше. Рефакторьте, я не думаю, что это займёт так много времени и в конечном итоге замените его на `Toolbar`.
Сам гугл рекомендует отказаться от прочего в пользу `Toolbar` и я считаю, что они правы. Удачи!